# Limit $(1+\frac{1}{a_n})(1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}} )\cdots(1+\frac{1}{a_1}) $ where $a_n=n(1+a_{n-1})$ and $a_1 =1$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $a_n=n(1+a_{n-1})$ and $a_1 =1$. Then the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{a_n})(1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}} )\cdots(1+\frac{1}{a_1}) $ where $n$ tends to infinity is? I got $1/2$ for answer is it correct?

Comment: in every bracets do the dominator thing and then replace the dominator with the recurrance and combine it with the next fraction for each bracket?

Comment: The first term in the product is $2$, and all terms are greater than $1$. I don't think the product tends to $1$.

Comment: check what I have posted,below

Comment: The answer has to be greater than $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\left(1+\frac1{a_1}\right)\left(1+\frac1{a_2}\right)\left(1+\frac1{a_3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac1{a_{n-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac{a_1+1}{a_1}\frac{a_2+1}{a_2}\frac{a_3+1}{a_3}\cdots\frac{a_{n-1}+1}{a_{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{a_2/2}{a_1}\frac{a_3/3}{a_2}\frac{a_4/4}{a_3}\cdots\frac{a_n/n}{a_{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{a_n}{a_1}\frac1{n!}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Induction shows that
$$
a_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}\tag{2}
$$
Plug $(2)$ into $(1)$ and we get 
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{a_1}\right)\left(1+\frac1{a_2}\right)\left(1+\frac1{a_3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac1{a_{n-1}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_1}\frac1{n!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\\[6pt]
&=e\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: oh yes i always calculate it as n ...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, ignore my previous post.  I realized something that makes my previous answer invalid.

I think the answer must be greater than 1.  The first term,

$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{a_1} \right) = 1 + \frac{1}{1} = 1 + 1 = 2 $$

Moreover, $a_n$ is a strictly positive sequence, so for all $n$,

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{a_n} > 1 $$

If your first term in the infinite product is 2, there is no way you can reduce the product by multiplying on terms that are greater than 1.

Comment: here is my solution in a second

Comment: Er sorry, see the new updated answer.  I realized something just now that I think makes it impossible for the answer to be 1.